# Lightning openfiles error

Tags: lightning-aura-components, controller, lightning-events

I am using `lightning:openFiles` to popup the file in lightning but after doing research and searching similar post in Stack exchange i am still unable to find out the error.

```
<aura:component controller="openfile" implements="forceCommunity:availableForAllPageTypes">
    <aura:attribute name="currentContentDocumentId" type="String" default="06928000005l5I4AAI"/>
    <p>{!v.currentContentDocumentId}</p>
    <ui:outputURL aura:id="url" click="{!c.openSingleFile}" label="Click here" 
                  value="{!v.currentContentDocumentId}"/>
</aura:component>
```

JS controller

```
({
    openSingleFile : function (component,event){                
        alert('hihih');
      var action = component.get("c.openfile1"); 
        var fireEvent = $A.get("e.lightning:openFiles");
      action.setCallback(this,function(actionResult) {
          //alert('inisde');
          //alert(actionResult.getReturnValue());
        var state = actionResult.getState();
          var id=actionResult.getReturnValue();
          alert(id);
          if (component.isValid() && state == "SUCCESS"){
              alert(state);
              component.set("v.currentContentDocumentId",actionResult.getReturnValue());
              }

      });

 $A.enqueueAction(action);
   fireEvent.fire({
                recordIds: [id]
            });      

},
});
```

Server side controller

```
public with sharing class openfile{
    @AuraEnabled
    Public static id openfile1(){
        system.debug('hihi');
        ContentVersion Cvid=[SELECT ContentDocumentId FROM ContentVersion where ContentDocumentId='06928000005l5I4AAI'];
        system.debug(Cvid.ContentDocumentId);
        return Cvid.ContentDocumentId;
    } 

}
```

The error here is :

> Cannot read property fire of undefined

Every thing looks fine here. Even I am setting the recordid here in **recordIds** attribute of **Lightning openFiles** event.
Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're in the wrong context. lightning:openFiles only works if you're inside LEX or S1. The error message you're getting is caused by $A.get returning an undefined value for e.lightning:openFiles (thus, it cannot "read property fire of undefined"). Here's the component I tested:

```
<aura:component implements="flexipage:availableForAllPageTypes">
    <aura:handler name="init" value="{!this}" action="{!c.openSingleFile}" />
</aura:component>
```

---

```
({
    openSingleFile : function (component,event){                
        var fireEvent = $A.get("e.lightning:openFiles");
        fireEvent.fire({
            recordIds: ["069500000033oBoAAI"]
        });      
    }
});
```

---

This does work as advertised, but not if you create your own `<aura:application>`. Instead, go to the Lightning App Builder in the setup screen, create a new app, add your component, and then activate it. It'll appear as a tab in your navigation menu when you go to the Lightning App that you activated for the custom app you built.

Comment: I got that point.It is also working in lightning page but it is directing to url which is not valid.Ideally after the link is clicked the file should be opened as popup if i am correct,but here it is directing to salesforce recordid url. `https://kmitcse-dev-ed.my.salesforce.com/one/06928000005l5I4AAI`.Which is not valid.

Comment: Shouldn't it also work in a component that is force:appHostable. I get the same issue on IOS with a force:appHostable app but strangely not if I open it in a chrome simulated as IOS

Comment: It also works fine in Chrome on my android device, event fires and the file downloads. Seems like an issue with the IOS SF1 app

Comment: Also works fine in Safari on IOS

Comment: @ScottMorrison It might be an issue with SF1. I don't have an Apple product to test on, though.

Comment: It's definitely an SF1 issue, throws the error in the SF1 app on android and  IOS even if the component is added to lightning app using lightning builder, and it works as expected from any browser on any device.

Comment: R&D is looking into it, I have a case open with salesforce and they were able to reproduce it.

Comment: @ScottMorrison, I am facing the same issue on SF1, this works fine on desktop but not SF1. Did salesforce R&D figure out a solution? If possible, could you please share the case details

Comment: No their solution was to update the docs. It's working as designed and is not supported in the sf1 app when chatter is off

Comment: I added the case comments as a solution for your enjoyment

Answer (score 1):

TLDR Summary

- The event is not supported in the SF1 app
- Docs were updated to reflect the limitation
- No timeline on when or if it will ever be supported

"As of now, the event is only supported for the mobile browser (one.app) and not within the downloadable applications on Android and iOS. The documentation is misleading without calling out that explicitly. Should your customer want to consider enabling Chatter and using Files within Salesforce1, the force:navigateToSObject within the downloadable apps will be the best option moving forward."

**NOTE:** force:navigateToSObject does not work with chatter and lex disabled for files.

***SF Support***

I completed my local testing of the lightning:openFiles component across various orgs and app versions. I get the same results as you, the Salesforce1 application on iOS and Android do not handle the event component correctly. Using that, an error message triggers that indicates the event component is undefined, just as you mentioned.

I have escalated this up to Tier 3 for further review. I'll be monitoring the escalation and will provide you additional information as it is made available to me.

***SF Support***

I hope you are well. I wanted to reach out and let you know that we are still reviewing the openFiles component in Salesforce1--specifically, the failure of that due to the undefined error that is thrown.

Tier 3 is still investigating, but once we have additional information to provide I'll make sure to update you with that promptly.

***SF Support***

I apologize for the delay, but our product team is still in the process of investigating the failure of the openFiles component on Salesforce1. They are woking hard to determine the root cause of the problem so they can check in a correct bug fix to resolve the behavior.

I'll continue to monitor that investigation and provide you updates as they are made available to me.

***SF Support***

Our product team is including this investigation into their work spring beginning Monday of next week. As such, I'll have more information to provide you next week on the progress made therein.

Please reach out if you have any questions, otherwise, you'll continue to hear from me with new information as it posted from the product team.

***Me***

Any progress on this issue? It's a really irritating bug. I worked around it by using e.force:navigateToURL to the absolute url of the download. This almost works except that it forces the user to login again which I'm sure you would agree is a horrible user experience. I tried to use frontdoor.jsp but the session id provided in apex doesn't allow for login and there's no way for me to get a first class session id because it's completely locked down by locker service on the client side. Is there a way in salesforce 1 get a session id that will allow login through frontdoor.jsp?

***SF Support***

My apologies for the length of time our product team is taking to triage this issue further. I have requested that Tier 3 engage and request a more meaningful update and potential workaround for interim usage.

I understand that the workaround with navigateToURL is not ideal as the session does not persist requiring re-login. There is not a means to request a session ID to use with frontdoor.jsp only because the Visualforce {!GETSESSIONID()} can’t be used therein. I believe you can only access a session ID if you have also built out the authentication, retrieving an access_token from an OAuth auth or are using an API call to return login results or session information.

I do hope to have more information for you from the product team soon.

***SF Support***

Just a quick follow up. If the navigateToURL event component is not working with the absolute download URL, are you able to navigate simply to the record ID of the file?

If you are able to retrieve that ID, you can use that for navigation purposes, setting your params to "url": "/dummyRecordID." The same could be done with the navigateToSObject event component too, where your params would be "recordId": "dummyRecordID."

If those are suitable for your use case, just let me know, otherwise we'll await further feedback from the product team.

***Me***

I tried that, but with ContentDocuments it throws a preview not available error and doesn't download the document, no preview, no download, no access. Now the custom is stuck with living with logging in multiple times to access documents from salesforce 1 or saving usernames and logins to get a valid session token. I'd also point out that salesforce 1 is not even in a visualforce context. Salesforce 1 is so locked down with locker service that there isn't really any reason to not provide a first class session token in that context, but really if openFiles worked as advertised there wouldn't be a problem

***SF Support***

Sorry to hear about the complications in navigating directly to the record. Is there a particular type of file that is failing to work, or is this just a standard document or photo file? Your example above is a PDF file, is that the one you're having issues with? We can investigate that failure in the interim of our product team continuing to work on the openFiles component for mobile.

***SF Support***

While I continue to review the ContentDocument record ID failure as you describe it (using navigateToURL and navigateToSObject), I wanted to let you know that the product team has uncovered a bit more information regarding our investigation--they've now officially logged a bug record to address this further. I don't yet know how or when they are going to fix this for full resolution, but it does look like something changed from version 12.3 iOS app to 13.0, specific to the undefined nature of that component. So they have a good starting point to reference for proceeding forward.

I apologize, I know this is a significant hurdle to your custom development. The team is working hard on prioritizing their work load. As we make more progress, I'll be sure to let you know the details.

***SF Support***

I hope you are well and had a nice weekend. I am not having the same issues with a simple example in my own demo org with a PDF document in Salesforce1, navigating to the record ID. That is successful for me, but I know you mentioned that in using that for your example there was no preview available and the content wouldn't download.

Are you using something other than a PDF in your customer implementation?

I can review that further if you'd like me to, just let me know if that is in the same org as attached above (XXXXXXXXXXXXXX) or a different org. Otherwise, we can continue to await some additional feedback from the product team on the bug record logged for the failure of the openFiles component in Salesforce1.

***Me***

Yes I am using a simple pdf, I tried with png, and doc files as well. What's the code your using to navigate to the document?

There are a couple of things to make sure of

1. Chatter is disabled in the org

I can navigate to the file record but the download action doesn't work for me. It is the same org. The test app is Download Test

***ME***

One other thing I should mention is that in the customers sandbox (I've granted access - XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX) They don't have chatter enabled.

I thought as of Spring 16 Files was available without chatter but I can't see the Files Home tab in their org and can't add it to the salesforce 1 app, that likely has something to do with not being able to navigate to the files record, but in my test the download action didn't work.

Having said that, having to tap the file, load another screen, then tap to download the file isn't exactly the user experience we're looking for.

Even if we can get these work arounds to work, can you confirm that the lightning:openFiles event should work in the salesforce1 app. And can you give an ETA on when it will be fixed?

***SF Support***

You are right, starting in Spring 16, you can use Salesforce Files whether Chatter is on or off. However, this is only applicable to the Salesforce1 mobile browser app, and not the Salesforce1 downloadable app, unfortunately. Files will not be available in the downloadable app if Chatter is off. Leaving that on will be key for accessing a Content Document object record by ID.

For example, Chatter is enabled in my demo org and I was able to successfully use:
$A.get('e.force:navigateToSObject').setParams({recordId: 'recordID'}).fire();

I can definitely understand the overly complex use case for accessing and actually downloading a file. Which makes the use of the openFiles component that much more appealing! I don't have much new information from the product team on the logged bug record, so I'll have Tier 3 reach out and get some further context on when this might be addressed.

***SF Support***

Again, my apologies for the length of time the product team is taking to review this component failure further. They have marked this as a lower priority in the face of some mobile-related bugs and features that require more devoted attention.

I've asked our Tier 3 support team to do a little gentle reminding on the bug record so the team can provide us some additional information soon. I hope to have a more substantial update by the end of the week.

***SF Support***

I've had our Tier 3 team request some additional information on our bug record so we can get some traction before the weeks end. They do not have any updates as of yet, but once we hear back, I'll be sure to reach out to you promptly. I know you've been patiently waiting for some direction regarding this bug, so I do appreciate you hanging in with us.

***ME***

In my dev org I have chatter turned off and LEX turned off but I can still see the Files tab in salesforce1 but I can't see it in the customers sandbox salesforce 1 instance. Is there a way to enable it?

The other thing is that in my dev org I can get to the detail page for the file, but the download action button at the bottom doesn't do anything, no errors, no download. I just want to confirm that you're actually able to download the file from there?

Can you also confirm that the lightning:openFiles event is supposed to work in salesforce1, and that the salesforce1 app and salesforce 1 browser mobile experience are designed to have different feature sets?

***SF Support***

Thanks for the reply. Are you still using this dev org: XXXXXXXXXXXXXX? I can see that the overall org settings for Chatter include the "Chatter and Global Search features" still enabled. Are you testing things, enabling and disabling that setting?

I can see what may be the difference between your org and your customers org if you can provide me the customers org ID as well.

As for the inability to download the file in your testing, is this on an iOS device using the downloadable Salesforce1 application? Do you have an appropriate application on your device to open the file within, I know there are differences in how iOS vs Android devices can handle downloads, given native device functionality. I'd be happy to review that too. If you want to add some screenshots I can take a look at that and see where the issue might be. Perhaps what would be best is if you can set me up as a test user in your dev org so I can login locally and review what you are experiencing.

If available to create/update, my email for a test user is: jennifer.mccarthy@salesforce.com. Please select the "Generate new password and notify User immediately" option prior to saving so that I may receive a password reset email to update the password to log in with on one of our local test devices.

As of our bug record, the team is working on prioritizing everything for our newest platform and app releases. I apologize it is taking so long, but we continue to re-engage and request updates as they are available. It is not clear from our testing at the support side whether the openFiles component was inadvertently made available for our downloadable apps or not. Given that the functionality is solid for desktop, LEX, and the mobile browser, it does seem like the complete failure on mobile could indicate this needs additional attention to make it compatible. But I cannot say for sure, so I would need to wait for confirmation from the team. I apologize for the delay.

***Me***

Yes I've been turning it on and off. I turned chatter and LEX on just to make sure that the openFiles event is undefined even when those are turned on and it is. Feel free to make any changes or run any tests you like on the dev org though as I created it specifically to demonstrate the issue.

***SF Support***

Thanks for that reply and the permission to review, test, and make necessary changes in your demo org. I'll take a look and see if I can identify what the difference might be therein.

***Me***

You're right, navigateToSObject works with chatter and LEX turned on, but once it's turned off you get a "you don't have permission to view this file" error. Bottom line is we need a solution that works with chatter and LEX turned off so that's where all the testing needs to focus. The customer can't turn chatter on for legal reasons and they have no plans to enable LEX.

***Me***

I've updated my test app with a button for each of the suggested methods, none of them produce the desired behavior, the closest is the absolute url but needing to log in when the session expires isn't great and it's not working in the customers org for some reason.

***SF Support***

Thanks for the reply. I'll take a look at your demo org with each custom button to review the behavior you describe. I understand none of the options are ideal, even the relative URL redirects you to an alternate login page. Are you still testing with Chatter enabled in your org? Does the root URL match the org domain when using the relative URL? That could introduce the behavior you describe.

Given that your customer cannot enable Chatter due to security and data concerns, are these options something you can consider for that implementation? Or do these still trigger the permissions error? The ability to open files or attachments in Salesforce1 is not supported with having Chatter enabled. There isn't an option for separating the Salesforce Files object and Chatter, so I'm curious to know the results you are getting with your customer's org.

***Me***

I just want to clarify that opening files in salesforce1 is supported when the lightning:openFiles event is used. As you know, in our testing this works very well from the mobile browser experience, it is only the salesforce1 application that is not working. This is a bug in the system as the documentation clearly states that salesforce1 is a supported platform for this event.

I understand that the Files tab is not supported if chatter is disabled, and any attempt to access files through this method such as navigateToSObject, or navigateToURL with the document id or content version id are not supported and will not work.

This makes it all the more critical that the lightning:openFiles bug in salesforce1 be fixed

***SF Support***

Definitely understood, I know that has been the overall inquiry with our support case since identifying the misbehavior with the openFiles event reference component in Salesforce1. Given that this returns as undefined, that is a valid concern! And as you mentioned, there is no documentation to indicate really one way or the other (supported for the downloadable apps or not).

I've had my support manager reach out to the product team to move this along faster. I apologize, we don't typically see the product team take such a long time to work an issue that so clearly needs to be addressed.

I hope to have some information to provide sometime this afternoon after our further efforts in reaching out yet again this morning.

***SF Support***

We have our various mobile-specific product teams coordinating together and confirming whether this event reference component is supported for our downloadable applications. Our docs call out the feature is supported in mobile, but does not specify if that is limited to only the mobile browser (as we know that does work successfully). So, once we have full confirmation from the team, I can help better clarify if this is something intended to be functioning on our downloadable applications or not. We will be sure to update our documentation around that as well.

Again, I apologize for the length of time this has taken to sort out. I appreciate your patience as we finalize the details of this.

***Me***

I will say I will be shocked if the conclusion is that the event should be supported only in the browser version of the salesforce 1 mobile app. The docs will need to be updated to specify compatibility between the salesforce1 mobile browser, and the salesforce 1 mobile native app for all lightning components and events to provide a clear line between the two platforms. I always assumed they were essentially the same running on the same infrastructure with the only difference being some extra functionality in the SF1 native app that could only be accomplished through a native app, is that assumption wrong?

***SF Support***

I agree, we do typically have greater clarity around supported contexts for a feature and make the effort to document that clearly. We failed to be so diligent this time around, and I apologize. To answer your question, there is a difference between our mobile browser and our downloadable applications. There are additional layers in our downloadable apps that can cause the app to handle events differently. We rely on native based implementations when we can for the downloadable app, but would change that over to web-based for mobile browser, really to make both the most optimal for their respective contexts. The downloadable app does use the webview from Safari or Chrome, but we do also put other code on top of those web based portions to help integrate with areas that might be strictly native to the device architecture.

We are making efforts to aim for that full parity across desktop, mobile browser, and downloadable apps, but do find that some features require a bit more effort to achieve that. This could very well be one of them. I apologize we did not determine that prior to publishing the feature as usable.

I've requested the team make that determination as fast as they can, so I can let you know.

***SF Support***

Our product team is still making the determination if this is supported for our downloadable applications.

My manager is aware this request has been pending for some time, and has reached out along side me for a meaningful update from the mobile product team. We will reach out again Monday morning, to get some further visibility and additional movement for final clarification around this for you. I'll monitor that into next week and let you know any new information supplied by the team.

***SF Support***

I am deeply sorry, but we still have not heard a definitive answer from our product team as to the supported contexts for the openFiles event reference component. I apologize for the wait, I know this is impacting you greatly. My manager continues to engage with the team to request updates that will not delay us any longer.

I'll have him reach out again tomorrow so I can monitor that communication and keep you updated as to what we hear back.

***SF Support***

I hope you are well. We have finally gotten some confirmation from our product team on the openFile component reference in Salesforce1.

As of now, the event is only supported for the mobile browser (one.app) and not within the downloadable applications on Android and iOS. The documentation is misleading without calling out that explicitly. Should your customer want to consider enabling Chatter and using Files within Salesforce1, the force:navigateToSObject within the downloadable apps will be the best option moving forward. The team will be investigating what it takes to make the openFile component available for the downloadable applications, handling that correctly to open the native file preview in app. However, I do not have a timeline for support of that feature. As of now, that is a user story they hope to integrate in a future version release.

**We will be pursuing a change to the documentation to call this out in greater detail. Again, I apologize it took so long to get confirmation on this feature. We aim to learn from this so that we do not miss such crucial information in our docs going forward.**

If I can help answer any final questions you may have, please just let me know.

***Me***

That's not an acceptable answer.

I can tell you exactly one way to make this event work in the SF1 navtive app. Use frontdoor.jsp with retURL set to the download link and the same logic you're using for openUrl to direct the user to the content and pass the first class session token that I know you have access to. LOE can't be more than a day.

I can't believe that salesforce is taking the position that their own lightning events may not be supported in their own native mobile application built on lightning, especially after all the hype about being mobile first.

This needs to be fixed

***SF Support***

I completely understand. To have to wait for such a long time for confirmation from our team, and then to hear that we have not yet identified a means we want to pursue to make this work across all contexts, is very frustrating. I apologize for the limitation and the oversight of our not documenting this correctly.

I'd be happy to chat with you on a phone call today or tomorrow if you would like. I may not have the greatest input on how our product team and engineers can implement this, but I can advocate for this feature to be supported for the downloadable apps in the future.

I am available today through 4pm PST and tomorrow between 7am - 4pm PST again. I don't have a phone number listed on the case to reach you, so please let me know the best number and time (with timezone) to call and I will follow up.

***SF Support***

Thank you for taking my call today. I do apologize for the limitations of the openFile component in the downloadable applications on Salesforce1. I agree, there are significant drawbacks of using the mobile browser, and with that as the only workaround here, you are left with no ideal options to provide your customer for the downloadable application.

I understand the frustration of having the Aura platform that is supported and mobile-centric, but finding out that there are still some areas of that platform that we have not addressed for full parity in all contexts.

I am awaiting some feedback from our product team to learn more about our roadmap and when we can anticipate this component being supported for the downloadable applications. Our doc team is already working on updating the documentation to reflect this. Rather than wait for the upcoming Winter release, they will make sure that change is published and released in a patch, aiming for next week.

I'll be sure to send you another update when I hear more about an estimated timeline for the full support of this component. I will be out of the office tomorrow, 7/28/2017 to return Monday 7/31/2017. If I don't hear anything by this afternoon, I will reach out again on Monday.

***SF Support***

I hope you are well. I wanted to reconnect on our case together. Our doc team was able to get an update to the developer docs around the openFile component event reference into this weeks patch. That will be releasing over Tues and Weds of this week. The change will point out that currently the component is supported only for the mobile browser Salesforce1 context at this time.

I am still awaiting some clarification on an anticipated timeline for support of this in the downloadable applications. Once I hear more on that I will be sure to update you with our roadmap.

***SF Support***

I appreciate your patience with us as we gain some additional insight into the openFiles event reference component and its support on the downloadable Salesforce1 applications.

The doc bug we've filed did get addressed quickly by the doc team. The patch update for that documentation will be released this week, over the course of today and tomorrow. We should see the update for that information by Thursday 8/3/2017.

As for the support of the openFiles event reference component in the apps and not just in mobile browser, we do not have a concrete date for that, unfortunately. We've requested that our downloadable app (both iOS and Android) product and engineering teams roadmap support for this in a future release, but currently they cannot accurately target a release version or timeframe with an expectation of delivery by that time. I apologize, but we don't yet have even a rough estimate as to when this might be supported.

Should you have any additional questions I can help answer or engage with our product team to help answer, please let me know. Otherwise, would it be possible to proceed in closing out this case?

Comment: It's kind of hard to tell how much of this answer is relevant. There's clearly a lot of content that has nothing to do with the question (signatures and whatnot), as well as a bunch of repeated information. Can you at least post a summary? Maybe put a little work into formatting so it's at least clear where each message begins and ends (since it looks like you just dumped an entire email thread).

Comment: Updated, sorry I scrubbed the greetings and signatures from the chatter feed. It's in chronological order now and I marked where SF supports comments start and where mine start. Hopefully that's clearer