# How to download content file data through lightning/visualforce

Tags: visualforce, lightning-aura-components, community, content

I am using content files to drive documentation about products in a lightning community.

I've researched the [ContentDocument](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/sforce_api_objects_contentdocument.htm) and [ContentVersion](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/sforce_api_objects_contentversion.htm) documentation but I am unable to figure how to get either the base64 value of the document, or the direct download url. Pasting the URL in the browser renders XML that says invalid session.

On ContentVersion there is a VersionData field that says its the base64 value of the content, but querying for it only returns a URL.[image]

I've also followed [this tutorial](http://developer.force.com/cookbook/recipe/displaying-salesforce-crm-content-documents-in-a-visualforce-page) on displaying content files on a visual force page but, but it just takes you to the record page and not the document.

Has someone implemented something similar?

Comment: Have you tried [lightning:openFiles](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/ref_lightning_openFiles.htm), as demonstrated in [this answer](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/a/174118)? Is that what you're looking for?

Comment: I'm going to look into this feature. Thanks @sfdcfox

Comment: @sfdcfox implemented your suggestion which shows the documents perfectly but the download button does not work. [See this question for details](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/176882/downloading-a-file-through-a-gete-lightningopenfiles-is-blocked-by-the-bro)

Answer (score 2):

The direct download link for the file is of the form: sfBaseUrl + /sfc/servlet.shepherd/version/download/ + ContentVersionId

The query editor shows the URL for VersionData but in Apex it is the correct type.

Comment: will servlet.shepherd change?

Comment: Doubtful since it's the same servlet to download files in classic

Comment: Just a heads up, you'll have to manipulate the base url a bit. the System.getBaseURL().toExternalForm returns a salesforce.com url, what you actually need is a force.com url.

https://test--partial.cs53.my.salesforce.com/sfc/servlet.shepherd/version/download/VersionID?asPdf=false

VS
https://test--Partial--c.cs53.content.force.com/sfc/servlet.shepherd/version/download/VersionID?asPdf=false

Comment: This almost works except it requires a new login

Comment: Actually it does work just didn't quite get it right :)

Comment: Actually not quiet, it requires a new login in the browser since salesforce one opens it in a new browser. How is open file not an event that can be triggered in SF1.

Comment: https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/ref_lightning_openFiles.htm I guess I should check the docs first :)

Comment: If you have a ContentDocument (id starts with 069), then you can obtain the ContentVersionId (which starts with 068) via: SELECT LatestPublishedVersionId FROM ContentDocument WHERE Id = '069...'