# Downloading a file through $A.get('e.lightning:openFiles') is blocked by the browser

Tags: lightning-aura-components, contentdocument

When this code is ran it opens the file successfully

```
var documentId = component.get('v.download').Content_ID__c;
$A.get('e.lightning:openFiles')
    .fire({
        recordIds : [documentId]
    });
```

When the file preview opens there is a menu bar on the top right with a download button.
[image]

When this is clicked nothing happens. In the console a warning, and an error is logged

Warning

> WARNING: Event.setParams(): 'inContextOfComponent'('forceContent:modalPreviewPlayer') is not a valid parameter. Valid parameters are 'recordId', 'allowPreview'

Error

> Spa.js:211 Blocked opening '' in a new window because the request was made in a sandboxed frame whose 'allow-popups' permission is not set.

This feature was working while it was on a persistent page, but I moved the link that calls the above JS to a modal that is rendered in between `aura:if` tags. The modal stays open in the background when the file is opened.

This is using a Chrome browser.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that I was testing this through the Community Builder Preview. When I deploy this to users and test it works as intended.

If you run into this issue just quickly deploy it to the users and test with a test community user.